# How do you call ActivePython from cygwin shell?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, python, cygwin

I installed ActivePython which is a Python version 3.x installation for Windows. I renamed the interpreter to be `activepython.exe` so as to allow calling it from cygwin without modifying `/etc/profile` path.

When I am in `cmd.exe` shell I can call ActivePython interpreter without arguments and enter interactive mode. When I execute the ActivePython interpreter from Cygwin shell, the shell just hangs indefinitely after hitting enter (similar to accounts seen by others [here](http://community.activestate.com/forum/activepython-251-cygwin)).

How do you call ActivePython from cygwin shell?

Answer (score 4):

Found a [blog post](http://pythontesting.net/python/interactive-python-cygwin-bas) with the solution here's a summary of the solution:

```
activepython -i
```

Notes:

- In my case I have ActivePython interpreter on the path as `activepython` to allow me to call activepython instead of the cygwin installed `python`.
- Tip: When you need to exit the interpreter `Ctrl-D` doesn't work. You need to do `Ctrl-C` and then the Cygwin shell freezes for 20 seconds before it becomes available again.
- I found a second more authoritative source on this exact subject. This source is the Cygwin terminal `mintty`. [Here the Cygwin developers are talking about the problem and they seem to talk about the low level issues with windows/mintty/python interpreter](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c12).

  - "This explicitly tells it to run in interactive mode. The reason it doesn't work otherwise is that it checks whether stdin is a console. With mintty and other pty-based terminals the answer is no, because Cygwin uses pipes to emulate ptys, so Python enters non-interactive mode."
  - "Unfortunately, not all Windows programs have a workaround like -i to force them to act interactively."

Comment: I believe that the `-i` open's the interpreter in 'interactive' mode.  Though I'm not for sure on this.

Comment: The `-i` is for interactive mode. But if you don't specify anything to the interpreter it usually enters interactive mode also. Which is I guess the reason for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Making the cygwin shell run from within cmd.exe worked very well for me:

I sued the following shortcut (check the cygwin path matches)

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /C C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat
```

Cygwin from within cmd.exe runs python without any odd problems